# Filter rows if value exists in array column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**NOTE: I'm working in Spark 2.4.4**

I have the following dataset

```
col1

['{"key1": "val1"}','{"key2": "val2"}']
['{"key1": "val1"}','{"key2": "val3"}']
```

Essentially, I'd like to filter out any rows where `key2` is not `val2`.

```
col1

['{"key1": "val1"}','{"key2": "val2"}']
```

In trino SQL, I'm doing it like this:

```
any_match(col1, x -> json_extract_scalar(x, '$.key2') = 'val2')
```

But this isn't available in Spark 2.4

My only idea is to explode and then use the following code which isn't efficient.

```
df.filter(F.get_json_object(F.col("col1"), '$.key2') == 'val2')
```

I'm wondering if I can do this without exploding in my version of spark (2.4.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spark >=2.4, you can use the [`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#exists) function of spark SQL.

```
df = df.withColumn('flag', F.expr('exists(col1, x -> get_json_object(x, "$.key2") == "val2")')) \
    .filter(F.col('flag')).drop('flag')
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. Just one small suggestion, you can just use `filter(F.col('flag'))`.

Comment: I have revised the answer based on your suggestion. Can you accept the answer，thank you！